# Positive integer solutions to $x^2+y^2+x+y+1=xyz$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

The question asks for positive integer solutions to $x^2+y^2+x+y+1=xyz$ .

We at first note that $x|y^2+y+1$. Now,let there exist positive integers $x,y$ that satisfy the given equation.Then $mx=y^2+y+1$ for some positive integer $m$ .Substituting this in the original equation yields

$$x^2+x+mx=xyz$$ $$\implies x+1+m=yz$$ $$\implies \dfrac{y^2+y+1}{m}+1+m=yz$$ $$\implies y^2+y+m^2+m+1=myz$$ This equation's exactly like the equation we were trying to solve.Unfortunately,however,this does not let us use FMID since we don't know if $m<x$.

The above problem is from Titu Andreescu's book on intro to diophantine equations.He does give a solution,but I was wondering if my approach could be used somehow.I am also interested in seeing other approaches.Thanks is advance.

Comment: All I can say is none of x,y can be even.

Comment: @awesome,why not?

Comment: Maybe I made a silly mistake, but I made z the subject and then I deduced that if one of them is even then z would be fractional.

Comment: @Awesome,can you explain in more details?If we can indeed prove that none of them can be even,the theorem can be proved using what I did in my post(I think so,anyway).

Comment: x^2+x:even; y^2+y:even; irrespective of their parities. add 1 to their sum: odd

Comment: @Awesome,I do.How else did my post format itself?

Comment: $mx=y^2+y+1$ does not imply that $m$ is even.

Comment: m and z are also odd...

Comment: Also, note that there are infinitely many positive integer solutions, e.g. $(x, y, z)=(3, 13, 5)$

Comment: @Awesome,and with that,I conclude that my brain is seriously tired and trying to procure solutions from stupid errors.Ignore my previous comments as I delete them.

Comment: @Ivan Loh,indeed,I was for some reason obsessed with proving the inexistence of solutions.There are an infinite number of solutions with $z=5$.However,now I want to know **why** I must at first prove that $z=5$.What must motivate me to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a classic example of a problem which is easily solved via [Vieta jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).

We may WLOG assume $x \geq y$. Let us define the "size" of a positive integer solution $(x, y, z)$ to be $x+y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and say that a solution is a smaller solution if its size is smaller.

Given a positive integer solution $(x, y, z)$ with $x>y\geq 1$, we shall use Vieta's formulas to obtain a smaller solution $(y, x', z)$ with $x>y \geq x' \geq 1$ (so $x+y>y+x'$).

Indeed, suppose we have a positive integer solution $(x, y, z)$ with $x>y \geq 1$. Rewrite the equation as $x^2+(1-yz)x+(y^2+y+1)=0$. Thus $x$ is a root of the quadratic $t^2+(1-yz)t+(y^2+y+1)=0$.

Let $x'$ be the other root. Vieta's formulas give $x+x'=yz-1, xx'=y^2+y+1$. The sum of roots equation tells us that $x'$ is an integer (since $x, yz-1$ are integers), and the product of roots equation tells us that $x'>0$ (since $x, y^2+y+1>0$), so $x'$ is indeed a  positive integer. Thus we get a positive integer solution $(y, x', z)$.

Since $x>y$, we have $x'=\frac{y^2+y+1}{x} \leq \frac{y^2+y+1}{y+1}<y+1$ so $x' \leq y<x$, as desired. Thus $(y, x', z)$ is indeed a **smaller** positive integer solution. (where smaller means $y+x'<x+y$)

**Note:** Here $x'$ is essentially the same as your $m$; note $x'=\frac{y^2+y+1}{x}$.

Now, starting from any positive integer solution $(x, y, z)$, we will "jump down" to a smaller positive integer solution as long as $x>y$. Since this cannot be done indefinitely (Every non-empty subset of the positive integers has a least element), we must eventually jump down to a base solution where $x=y$.

When $x=y$, we get $2y^2+2y+1=y^2z$ so $y \mid 1$ so $y=1$, so $z=5$. Thus the only base solution is $(x, y, z)=(1, 1, 5)$. Now, if we start from an arbitrary positive integer solution, then after jumping down some finite number of times, we must reach a base solution, which we have shown must be $(1, 1, 5)$. Thus all positive integer solutions of the orginal equation may be recovered by "jumping back up", i.e. reversing the process of getting a smaller solution explained above.

Note that $z$ remained constant throughout the process of jumping, so we have $z=5$ throughout. We have $x+x'=yz-1=5y-1$, so we may reverse the jump and "jump up" from $(y, x', 5)$ to $(5y-1-x', y, 5)$.

Thus all positive integer solutions are given by $(x_n, y_n, 5)$ where $x_1=y_1=1$, and $(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}, 5)=(5x_n-1-y_n, y_n, 5)$. If we define an auxillary recurrence $a_1=a_2=1, a_{n+1}=5a_n-1-a_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$, then all positive integer solutions are given by $(x, y, z)=(a_{n+1}, a_n, 5)$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The first few terms of the recurrence $a_n$ are $1, 1, 3, 13, 61, 291$. Checking in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+3%2C+13%2C+61%2C+291&language=english&go=Search) gave this exact problem.

Oh, and if you relax the assumption $x \geq y$, you just get $(x, y, z)=(a_{n+1}, a_n, 5)$ and $(x, y, z)=(a_n, a_{n+1}, 5)$