# How to find all $m,n$ such that $mn|m^2+n^2+1$?

Tags: number-theory

How to find all positive integers $m,n$ such that $m|n^2+1$ and $n|m^2+1$ ?

My work:- Let $n^2+1=mk , m^2+1=ng$ , then $mkg=gn^2+g=m^2n+n+g$ , hence

$m|n+g$ i.e. $m|n+\dfrac{m^2+1}n$ i.e. $\dfrac{n^2+m^2+1}{mn}$ is an integer i.e. $mn|m^2+n^2+1$ . Now conversely

assume $mn|m^2+n^2+1$ , then $m|m^2+n^2+1$ and $n|m^2+n^2+1$ i.e. $m|n^2+1$ and $n|m^2+1$

So the question equivalently asks to positive integers $m,n$ such that $mn|m^2+n^2+1$

Comment: Do you know whether this problem have a nice solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This is a classic example of a problem that may be solved  by [Vieta jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping). All solutions are given by $(m, n)=(F_{2k-1}, F_{2k+1})$ or $(m, n)=(F_{2k+1}, F_{2k-1})$, where $F_n$ are Fibonacci numbers. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762895/positive-integer-solutions-to-x2y2xy1-xyz/763182#763182) for an example of how I use Vieta jumping to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write a formula and although it is possible to draw some more.

Solutions of the equation: $\frac{X^2+aX+Y^2+bY+c}{XY}=j$

If a root. $t=\sqrt{(b+a)^2+4c(j-2)}$

Then using the equation Pell:  $p^2-(j^2-4)s^2=1$

Solutions can be written:

$X=\frac{(b+a\pm{t})}{2(j-2)}p^2+(t\mp{(b-a)})ps-\frac{(b(3j-2)+a(6-j)\mp{(j+2)t})}{2}s^2$

$Y=\frac{(b+a\pm{t})}{2(j-2)}p^2+(-t\mp{(b-a)})ps-\frac{(b(6-j)+a(3j-2)\mp{(j+2)t})}{2}s^2$

Please note that the number $p,s$ Can be any characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at here. If we take $a=b=0, c=1, j=3$, so $t=2$, your claimed solution reduces to $X=\pm p^2+2ps \pm 5s^2, Y=\pm p^2-2ps \pm 5s^2$. If we choose the positive sign and take $p=s=1$, we get $X=8, Y=4$, but this is **not** a solution to $\frac{X^2+Y^2+1}{XY}=3$.

Comment: Ah, it appears that you want to restrict $p, s$ to be solutions of the relevant Pell equation. Your last sentence "Please note that the number $p, s$ Can be any characters" was confusing.

Comment: Google sometimes incorrectly translates. $p,s$ number of course there are solutions of Pell's equation. And they defined them.