# Given a Pell “solution” in [integer] polynomials, what can be said about the components?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $x,y$ be integers, and $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$, and $h(x,y)$ be polynomials in $x$ and $y$ with integer coefficients such that
$$
f(x,y)^2 - g(x,y)h(x,y)^2 = 1. \qquad(\star)
$$
Furthermore, assume it can be proven that $g(x,y)$ is a (possibly unknown) non-square integer $d$, so that we can write $(u,v)=\left(f(x,y),h(x,y)\right)$ and $(\star)$ becomes the Pell equation $u^2-dv^2=1$.

What can now be said about the components of $(\star)$? Evidently, we have the easy conclusions that $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$, and $h(x,y)$ are pairwise relatively prime, and that $f(x,y)/h(x,y) \approx \sqrt{g(x,y)}$.

Is there anything else substantive we can deduce in general? Does the additional restriction $\gcd(x,y)=1$ allow anything further to be deduced?

EDIT: Here are a couple of interesting resources/papers dealing with special cases of $(\star)$.

Nathanson http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2041581?uid=3739448&uid=2&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21104074640901

Yakota http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X10000363 and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X04000228

Comment: There are several formulas.   For example this.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800065/how-to-find-all-m-n-such-that-mnm2n21/800662#800662  The simple sense everywhere.  Transformation toward a more simple equation Pell.

Comment: @individ: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If, say, I have
$$
  (2x+3y)^2 - (4x^2+1)(7x^2y^3)^2 = 1, \quad(\star)
$$
what can I say about $x,y$, or any of $2x+3y$, $4x^2+1$, or $7x^2y^3$? [Note: I arbitrarily chose all of the coefficients, so I honestly don't know if $(\star)$ has any rational solutions.]

Comment: This is not the Pell equation. And it has always a finite number of solutions.

Comment: It *is* the Pell equation: set $u=2x+3y$, $d=4x^2+1$, and $v=7x^2y^3$, and we have $u^2-dv^2=1$.

Comment: In the Pell equation $d$ - there is a constant coefficient.

Comment: $4x^2+1$ is a constant coefficient when $x$ is a fixed integer.

Comment: no. It is another.